# Alterar Página de Categoria Woocommerce Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Boa noite pessoal tudo certo ?

Estou com uma pequena duvida, eu gostaria de ajustar minha página de listagem de produtos de categoria igual a minha home desse meu site http://enprodutos.com.br/ obs: fiz um Shortcode no function.php que faz listar desse seguinte modo 'titulo', 'valor' 'inf1' e 'inf2', eu gostaria que minha pagina de categoria que lista os produtos conforme a categoria que o usuário selecione fique no mesmo modo, não encontro de modo algum o arquivo para eu editar e nem sei por onde começar

Comment: Para customizar os templates você pode copiar o diretório `templates` do woocommerce, para seu tema alterando o nome para `woocommerce`. Desta forma os arquivos do seu tema serão considerados. É necessário copiar somente os arquivos que serão alterados.
Exemplo: Copiar: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` para `wp-content/themes/TEMA/woocommerce/archive-product.php`

Falando especificamente da página de categorias, os arquivos que deve considerar são o `archive-product.php` e também os contidos no diretório `loop`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda compreendi o funcionamento, fiz uma personalização conforme a solicitação do meu cliente grande abraços e espero puder te reatribuir algum dia com conhecimento

Comment: Consegui resolver conforme o código a baixo, mas também queria saber como consigo listar somente a categoria selecionada

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver o meu problema, o meu código ficou do seguinte modo, dentro do meu tema 
tema/woocommerce/archive-product.php

```
                    <div class="wc-products">
                        <ul class="products">
                            <?php
                                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'product-category' => 'shoes', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
                                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                                    <h2>Shoes</h2>

                                        <li class="product">    

                                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                                                <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                                                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>

                                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                                                <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    

                                            </a>

                                            <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

                                        </li>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                    </ul><!--/.products-->
                </div>
```